# Python msn hook - possible?

Tags: python, hook, msn

Is it possible to hook msn via a python application to send messages to your contacts etc?

Comment: msn is a portal. I assume you mean Microsoft's Hotmail or Messenger services. I suspect that would entail a large amount of soul-destroying reverse-engineering effort, unless some already-lost soul has gone and built a library for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [twisted.words.protocols.msn](http://twistedmatrix.com/) or use libpurple through its [DBus bindings](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto) or [Python bindings](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/PythonHowTo).